# How can I place a marker in React Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react leaflet library in my project and attempting to show a marker on my map view by using a `Marker` component, following [this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-add-a-react-leaflet-marker-with-a-popup-to-a-map) on Egghead along. However, it doesn't display but a broken image, as follows:

[Current view so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGBhC.png)

And this is the implementation in my project:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconUrl: ('./markers/marker.png')
});

  // my current implementation
  <MapContainer
    center={[19.000855082428515, -98.19408389636365]}
    zoom={13} >
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    
    <Marker
      position={[19.000855082428515, -98.19408389636365]}>
      <Popup>
        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>
```

I´ve also used the `icon` property of `Market` set up with this function outside my Component:

```
const getIcon = () => (
  new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: require('./markers/marker.png'),
    iconSize: [35, 35]
  })
);
// code 
<Marker
   icon={getIcon()}
   position={[19.000855082428515, -98.19408389636365]}>
 //code
```

What is the issue that doesn't allow the market to show up? or is there another way to get the marker to show up?

Answer (score 0):

I at last found my way to resolve my issue. Fortunately, this has been answered some years ago on GitHub with the issue [#453](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/453).
What works for me was removing the `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';` line and replace it in the HTML index file for the `link` tag specified on [their documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) and ta-da, happy in the end